# How to make H2 return results faster for a big resultset?

Tags: hibernate, query-optimization, h2

In a batch application, I use a temporary file-based H2 database to store 3M rows. The DB size is 9GB.

At the end of the batch, I export the content of the DB to a newline-delimited JSON file. This is basically a big Hibernate `JOIN` query and then iterating on the resultset to write in the resulting file. The resulting file size is approx 5GB.

Executing the `JOIN` query to obtain a `ScrollableResults` objects takes around 6 minutes. I could probably optimize this but that's still ok to me.

My problem is that the next operation, copying from the `ScrollableResults` to the report File is extremely slow. It takes 30 minutes to complete. A quick check on VisualVM's CPU sampler shows that most of the time is spent in `org.h2.store.WriterThread.run()` and `org.h2.store.fs.FileDisk.read()`.

[image]

From this I understand that what takes most time is writing the results in the result buffer h2 keeps on the hard disk, and reading from it. Since the result set is quite big, I cannot store it in memory. What are my other options to make this operation run faster ?

NB : To make sure the disk performances (it's an SSD disk on Google Compute Engine) were not responsible for this, I used the `cp` command to backup the 9GB db to another file, and it took 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation on the results you got: The `WriterThread` has a CPU time of 0, because it is waiting (sleeping) most of the time. The `FileDisk.read` could be reading from the database file, or reading from an large result set (in H2, large result sets are written to disk in most cases). So it's not really clear yet whether the problem is really that a temporary result set is created.

To analyze performance bottlenecks, what I would do is analyze the most frequent stack traces. This will show where and why it is slow. Now, all you see is there it is slow, but not why (what other method called it).

If the problem is really that a temporary result set is stored to disk, then the only solution I know (as of now) is to avoid large result sets.